# GridView not updating after notifyDataSetChanged()

Tags: android, gridview, notifydatasetchanged

GridView not updating after `notifyDataSetChanged()`
called

I have a Fragment which has a GridView which displays images from a particular folder , `onclick` it takes to a new `Activity` where the file is deleted and a broadcast is send to update the GridView.
I have tried `notifyDataSetChanged()` but still the GridView is not updated, the file is actually deleted and the mediastore is updated using

```
String path = newString;
File myFile = new File(path);
boolean deleted = myFile.delete();
ContentResolver resolver = getContentResolver();
deleteFileFromMediaStore(resolver, myFile);
```

and

```
public void deleteFileFromMediaStore(final ContentResolver contentResolver, final File file) {
        String canonicalPath;

            try {
                canonicalPath = file.getCanonicalPath();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                canonicalPath = file.getAbsolutePath();
            }
            final Uri uri = MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external");
            final int result = contentResolver.delete(uri,
                    MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATA + "=?", new String[] {canonicalPath});
            if (result == 0) {
                final String absolutePath = file.getAbsolutePath();
                if (!absolutePath.equals(canonicalPath)) {
                    contentResolver.delete(uri,
                            MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATA + "=?", new String[]{absolutePath});
                }
            }

    }
```

this is the code I am trying

```
public class ImageGalfrag extends Fragment {
    private Cursor cursor;
     private int columnIndex;
    ImageView thumbV;
    ImageButton videoICON;
    GridView sdcardImages;
    ArrayList<Bitmap> bitmapArray = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
    public static final String BROADCAST_UPDATE = "com.quest.fsrecorder.CommonFrags.ImageGalfrag.UPDATE";
//   @Override
//    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    final BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent1) {

                String action = intent1.getAction();

                  if (action.equals((BROADCAST_UPDATE))) {
                      ReloadImages();
                  }

        }
    };

    private void BroadCastDetails() {

            IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
            intentFilter.addAction(BROADCAST_UPDATE);
            getActivity().registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, intentFilter);

    }

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.gallery_gridview, container, false);
}
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        BroadCastDetails();
        //setContentView(R.layout.gallery_gridview);
        try {
            String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.Media._ID,
                    MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA,
                    MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE,
                    MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_MODIFIED};

            cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                    projection, // Which columns to return
                    MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA + " " +
                            "like ? ",
                    new String[]
                            {"%/" + getResources().
                                    getString(R.string.string_store_Images_folder) + "/%"},
                    MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_MODIFIED);
            View v = getView();
            // Get the column index of the Thumbnails Image ID
            columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID);
            sdcardImages = (GridView) v.findViewById(R.id.PhoneImageGrid);
            sdcardImages.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(getActivity()));
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private Context context;
        public ImageAdapter(Context localContext) {
            context = localContext;
        }
        public int getCount() {
            return cursor.getCount();
        }
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }
        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ImageView imageView;
            View grid = null;
            try {
               // LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
                if (convertView == null) {


                        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService
                                (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );
                        //grid = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gallery_view, null);
                    grid = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gallery_view, parent, false);


                } else {
                    grid = (View) convertView;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            cursor.moveToPosition(position);
            int imageID = cursor.getInt(columnIndex);
            //grid = new View(mContext);

            TextView textView = (TextView) grid.findViewById(R.id.grid_text);
            textView.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE)));
            thumbV = (ImageView) grid.findViewById(R.id.thumbImage);
//            thumbV.setImageURI(Uri.withAppendedPath(
//                    MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, "" + imageID));
                         String path =
                                 cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA));

                        path = "file:///" + path;
                        Glide.with(getActivity()).load(path)
                                .into(thumbV);
            final String  Data = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA));
            ImageButton deleteBtn = (ImageButton)grid.findViewById(R.id.delete_btn);
            deleteBtn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);


            grid.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override

                public void onClick(View v) {

                    //Do something
                    try {

                        String[] projection1 = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA, MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_MODIFIED};
                        Cursor cursor1 = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                                projection1, // Which columns to return
                                MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA + " " +
                                        "like ? ",
                                new String[]
                                        {"%/" + getResources().
                                                getString(R.string.string_store_Images_folder) + "/%"},
                                MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_MODIFIED);
                        columnIndex = cursor1.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
                        cursor1.moveToPosition(position);
                        String imagePath = cursor1.getString(columnIndex);
                        Intent ImageIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), ZoomImageView.class);
                        ImageIntent.putExtra("ImageName", imagePath);

                        getActivity().startActivity(ImageIntent);

                    }
                    catch (Exception e ){

                    }

                }
            });



            return grid;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        sdcardImages.invalidateViews();
        sdcardImages.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(getActivity()));
    }

    public void ReloadImages(){
         ImageAdapter  adapteraa = new ImageAdapter(getActivity());
        adapteraa.notifyDataSetChanged();
        sdcardImages.setAdapter(adapteraa);

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
       getActivity().unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have already set an adepter in onActivityCreated method to your gridview. You need not to reinitialise it agin in reloadImage() method. Just make it globle and reinitialize it only if it is null. And if it is not null just call notifyDataSetChanged.

```
public void ReloadImages(){
              if(adapteraa == null){
                 adapteraa = new ImageAdapter(getActivity());
                 sdcardImages.setAdapter(adapteraa);
              } else{
                adapteraa.notifyDataSetChanged();
             }
    }
```

And never call a notify method befor setting an adpter to a gridview.

Answer (score 1):

You are notifying the adapter before setting it so you can't see the changes,

```
public void ReloadImages(){
        ImageAdapter  adapteraa = new ImageAdapter(getActivity());
        sdcardImages.setAdapter(adapteraa);
        adapteraa.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Second your `Cursor` still with the same data you need to reload it to at `ReloadImages` method